# Deleting directories starting with certain name from HDFS in Java

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

i am trying to delete hive stage files from spark using the below code. This code can delete files in a directory, but i want to delete all file starting with '.hive-staging_hive'.

Can i know the way to delete the directories starting with certain text.

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            System.out.println("560");
            Path output = new Path("hdfs://abcd/apps/hive/warehouse/mytest.db/cdri/.hive-staging_hive_2017-06-08_20-45-20_776_7391890064363958834-1/");
            FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

            System.out.println("564");

            // delete existing directory
            if (hdfs.exists(output)) {
                System.out.println("568");
                hdfs.delete(output, true);
                System.out.println("570");

            }
```

Comment: I think you can do this with a shell script easily. Are you open to a bash solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to run a process form Java program and use a wildcard to delete all the files starting with **".hive-staging_hive"** in a directory.

```
String command="hadoop fs -rm pathToDirectory/.hive-staging_hive*";
int exitValue;
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
    exitValue = process.exitValue();
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot run command");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The next way is to list all files in the directories. Filter the files that starts with **".hive-staging_hive"** and delete them.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp");

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), conf);

FileStatus[] fileStatus = fs.listStatus(path);

List<FileStatus> filesToDelete = new ArrayList<FileStatus>();

for (FileStatus file: fileStatus) {

    if (file.getPath().getName().startsWith(".hive-staging_hive")){
        filesToDelete.add(file);
    }
}


for (int i=0; i<filesToDelete.size();i++){
    fs.delete(filesToDelete.get(i).getPath(), true);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shankar. The second apporach you mentined is helpful. I tried that.. but they are not pulling ".hive-staging_hive" directories. I am receiving only the regular partition directories. Can i know why they are not pulling staging directories?

Comment: If i try the first approach earilier, i am getting 'hadoop command not found' error. My Spark cluster is outside of hadoop cluster. May be my spark program is not submitting 'hadoop fs ' command to hadoop cluster.

Comment: Hello @AKC I have updated the second part of the answer which should work. I have tested in the local as well.

Comment: It worked for me. thank you. On the second approach you mentioned how to i use it to delete multiple files with some regular expression such as *_my*.